# how to show only shared files in google picker popup

Tags: google-picker

I am very new to google picker and any google apis.I have integrated google picker api successfully in my project.But I want to show only shared picture in picker popup.Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean showing pictures that is owned by someone else and shared to you, you can use

```
DocsView.setOwnedByMe(boolean | undefined)
```

From the documentation at [Google Picker Reference](https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/reference#DocsView)

```
Filters the documents based on whether they are owned by the user, or shared with the user.
```

Comment: I couldn't actually get this to work, do you have an example you could share?